# Directory.GetFiles return null on xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

```
 var folder = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Viber";


                         if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                             Console.WriteLine("folder exist");
                         else
                             Console.WriteLine("doesnt exist");

                        
                          var filelist = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
```

while folder exist filelist is returned null, i use all getfiles overloads, the folder of course is full, i use xamarin for android with c#, what is the problem?

Comment: Do you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for Android? It has to be in the Android.Manifest and it might be needed to be asked at runtime also

Comment: Please your IF is inversed !!! you make a mistake with !

Comment: On an Android 11 device.

Comment: `filelist is returned null` Not null but an empty list i think.

Comment: Like blackapps said, the filelist is null. No files in the folder. You could check on your device folder. The path you provided is public external storage.  You could check the link below for more details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

Better !!!

```
if (Directory.Exists(folder))
    Console.WriteLine("folder exist");
else
    Console.WriteLine("doesnt exist");

var filelist = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
```